# Checking whether a checkbox is checked

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox

I have not found any inbuilt function for checking whether a checkbox is set true or false,
isChecked() is not available is apps-script (if i am right). 
Any idea on how to find it or we shall have a value change handler to count the number of times the value changed and find if it is checked or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign your checkbox a name so that you can retrieve its value in a handler function with e.parameter.checkboxname : this value is boolean.

```
var chkmode = app.createCheckBox("description").setName("chk1").setId("chk1")
```

with the ID you can modify its state from the handler function (or from any other) if necessary (getElementbyId())

note that the handler can be on the checkbox itself (a change handler) or on any other element in the UI, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, however I believe there is a problem with the checkBox status, even though its status looks like boolean, it doesn't behave like boolean but like string

1. if you print in a spreadsheet e.parameter.myCheckBox you will get TRUE or FALSE
2. if you print in a spreadsheet e.parameter you will get the whole object and see myCheckBox=true or myCheckBox=false
3. however, if (e.parameter.myCheckBox) will always return True
4. the workaround I am using is: if (e.parameter.myCheckBox == "true") will return the actual myCheckBox status

Just in case, I am opening a new ticket in the issue tracker
I hope this would help you

ps. confirmed with Google, e.parameter.myCheckBox is a string, not a boolean

if you want to use it as boolean it would be like (e.parameter.myCheckBox == "true")

Comment: Values in e.parameter.something are indeed strings, so in your last edit you should have written `(e.parameter.myCheckBox == 'true')`

Answer (score 1):

```
var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('tellStatus');
```

and then (as example showing it in a label)

```
function tellStatus(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('yourStatusLabel').setText('Checkbox checked: ' + e.parameter.yourCheckbox)
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use handler function look like below.

I found example from https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/uiapp-examples-code-snippets/check-box

```
if(e.parameter['checkbox_isChecked_'] == 'true'){
      itemsSelected+= e.parameter['checkbox_value_']+',';
    }
```